# cannot change screen brightnes

Tags: release-loki, brightness

Hi I have just installed Elementary OS Loki 0.4.1, on to my acer aspire 5742 PEW71 laptop. I have it dual booted with windows 7 which can alter screen brightness, however when i change the brightness in windows 7 it does not alter Element OS.
It has received all the latest updates and have tried the following:

1. `xbacklight`
2. ```
   cd /sys/class/backlight/*/ 
   sudo chmod 777 ./brightness 
   sudo echo $(cat max_brightness) > ./brightness``
   ```

Comment: Please include relevant hardware information like computer/laptop, which brand which version etc.

Comment: Hi peter, i have included the laptop model, is there any other information that i can add,  that may be of use

Comment: I would try searching on something like "Acer Aspire brightness ubuntu". (Ubuntu because ElementaryOS is build on it and it's a very common Linux distro) It might be a driver issue. See for example: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2200860

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally posted by divergex:

> Here is the solution that worked on my Aspire 5740; In the terminal, run:
>
> ```
> sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> when the file opens, look for the line similar to:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash"
> ```
>
> and add `acpi_osi=` to the list, so it looks like:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash acpi_osi="
> ```
>
> save the file, then exit gedit. Next, be sure to run:
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> to make the changes permanent. Exit the terminal and reboot.